# Emulating PPC Arch on linux

Tags: linux, qemu

I am currently trying to get a PowerPC architecture emulated running using qemu-kvm on my centos box.

I currently have qemu-kvm installed however I see a lot of tutorials https://gmplib.org/~tege/qemu.html

utilizing this qemu-system-* call to create the emulated architecture?

is there a new way of creating these enviorments with just the qemu-kvm or do I need to some how find this qemu-system-* calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use plain QEMU, not QEMU + KVM.

KVM uses Intel VT or AMD-V to emulate an x86 system from another x86 system. It does not support emulating PPC or any other architecture on x86. Regular QEMU will use software emulation to simulate the PPC processor in x86 code.

Comment: virtualization vs emulation